# Pyspark mapInPandas failing intermittently with timeout/connection errors

Tags: python, pandas, windows, networking, pyspark

I am running into intermittent timeout and "Python worker failed to connect back" errors when using mapInPandas, reproduced by the following script. If I run this script several times in succession it will sometimes even alternate between working and failing. Other times it will fail repeatedly.

```
# reproduce_error.py
import os
import sys
os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
os.environ['PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
import pandas as pd
import pyspark
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from typing import Iterator
from pyspark.sql.types import (
    StructType, StructField, StringType)

print('environment:')
import platform # only need this for showing environment
print(f'OS: {platform.system()} {platform.release()}')
print('Python:', sys.version)
print('pandas:', pd.__version__)
print('pyspark:', pyspark.__version__)
for k in [
    'JAVA_HOME','HADOOP_HOME','SPARK_HOME',
    'PYSPARK_PYTHON','PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON','PATH']:
    print(f'{k}: {os.environ[k]}')

# start spark
conf = SparkConf().setAll([
    ('spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled','true'),
    ('spark.sql.shuffle.partitions','1')
])
spark_session = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()

# create input
schema = StructType([
    StructField('col1', StringType(),  True),
    StructField('col2', StringType(),  True)
])
inpt = spark_session.createDataFrame(
    [('A','B'),('C','D')], schema=schema)

# confirm can convert to pandas dataframe as a sanity check
print(inpt.toPandas())

# apply pandas udf that does nothing
def pandas_udf_noop(iterator: Iterator[pd.DataFrame]) -> Iterator[pd.DataFrame]:
    for pdf in iterator:
        yield pdf
outpt = inpt.mapInPandas(
    pandas_udf_noop, schema=schema)
outpt.show() # error occurs at this line

# tear down
spark_session.stop()
```

Additional context:

0. The above is a minimal example trying to reproduce an error I'm getting in more
   complex/longer code involving pandas udfs with mapInPandas. The latter was previously reliably working/passing
   tests for months, same virtual machine. With the real code I am also seeing
   "Exception: could not open
   socket: ["tried to connect to ('127.0.0.1', 56838), but an error occurred: [WinError
   10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"]"
   but I'm not able to reproduce that with any simple examples I tried--I will leave that
   for another post but mentioning it in case it gives someone a clue about what's going
   on.
1. I am not running this on my personal computer but rather logging into a virtual
   machine via RDP at work and running there. There is a firewall and security software
   running.
2. I am using the same environment variables (JAVA_HOME, SPARK_HOME, HADOOP_HOME,
   PYSPARK_PYTHON, PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON) with which my code worked previously, so
   they are likely not the essential culprit (although I'm open to changing them).
3. Between when my code was last known to work/pass tests and now, IT did some updates on this virtual machine, including installing a newer version of Java, updating the security
   software, and doing Windows updates.
   The version of Java I was using before is still there and I am pointing to it with
   JAVA_HOME.

Here is the output from a time the script above errored:

> ```
> C:\Users\[me]\Documents\reproduce_spark_udf_error>SET JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211
> C:\Users\[me]\Documents\reproduce_spark_udf_error>SET SPARK_HOME=C:\spark\spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2
> C:\Users\[me]\Documents\reproduce_spark_udf_error>SET HADOOP_HOME=C:\hadoop\hadoop-3.2.0
> C:\Users\[me]\Documents\reproduce_spark_udf_error>SET PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%HADOOP_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
> C:\Users\[me]\Documents\reproduce_spark_udf_error>python reproduce_error.py
> environment:
> OS: Windows 10
> Python: 3.8.5 (default, Sep  3 2020, 21:29:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
> pandas: 1.1.3
> pyspark: 3.1.2
> JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211
> HADOOP_HOME: C:\hadoop\hadoop-3.2.0
> SPARK_HOME: C:\spark\spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2
> PYSPARK_PYTHON: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe
> PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe
> PATH: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\bin;C:\hadoop\hadoop-3.2.0\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\msys64\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\;C:\Users\[me]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
> Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
> Setting default log level to "WARN".
> To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
> 22/07/26 16:11:36 WARN ProcfsMetricsGetter: Exception when trying to compute pagesize, as a result reporting of ProcessTree metrics is stopped
>   col1 col2
> 0    A    B
> 1    C    D
> 22/07/26 16:13:07 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 8)/ 4]
> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
>         at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:182)
>         at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:107)
>         at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:119)
>         at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:145)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.MapInPandasExec.$anonfun$doExecute$1(MapInPandasExec.scala:81)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:898)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:898)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
>         at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
>         at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
>         at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
>         at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForNewConnection(Native Method)
>         at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:135)
>         at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:409)
>         at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:199)
>         at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)
>         at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:513)
>         at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:174)
>         ... 20 more
> 22/07/26 16:13:07 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 8) ([vm url] executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
>         at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:182)
>         at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:107)
>         at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:119)
>         at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:145)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.MapInPandasExec.$anonfun$doExecute$1(MapInPandasExec.scala:81)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:898)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:898)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
>         at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
>         at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
>         at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
>         at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForNewConnection(Native Method)
>         at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:135)
>         at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:409)
>         at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:199)
>         at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)
>         at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:513)
>         at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:174)
>         ... 20 more
>
> 22/07/26 16:13:07 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 1 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "reproduce_error.py", line 48, in <module>
>     outpt.show()                                                    (0 + 3) / 4]
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py", line 484, in show
>     print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1304, in __call__
>     return_value = get_return_value(
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 111, in deco
>     return f(*a, **kw)
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
>     raise Py4JJavaError(
> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o71.showString.
> : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 8) ([vm url] executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
>         at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:182)
>         at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:107)
>         at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:119)
>         at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:145)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.MapInPandasExec.$anonfun$doExecute$1(MapInPandasExec.scala:81)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:898)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:898)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
>         at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
>         at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
>         at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
>         at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForNewConnection(Native Method)
>         at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:135)
>         at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:409)
>         at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:199)
>         at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)
>         at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:513)
>         at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:174)
>         ... 20 more
>
> Driver stacktrace:
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2258)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2207)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2206)
>         at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
>         at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
>         at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2206)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1079)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1079)
>         at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1079)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2445)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2387)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2376)
>         at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:868)
>         at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2196)
>         at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2217)
>         at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2236)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:472)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:425)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:47)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3696)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$head$1(Dataset.scala:2722)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3687)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3685)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2722)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2929)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:301)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:338)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>         at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
>         at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
>         at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
>         at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>         at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
>         at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
>         at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:182)
>         at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:107)
>         at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:119)
>         at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:145)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.MapInPandasExec.$anonfun$doExecute$1(MapInPandasExec.scala:81)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:898)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:898)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
>         at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
>         at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
>         at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>         ... 1 more
> Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
>         at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForNewConnection(Native Method)
>         at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:135)
>         at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:409)
>         at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:199)
>         at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)
>         at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:513)
>         at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:174)
>         ... 20 more
>
>
> C:\Users\[me]\Documents\reproduce_spark_udf_error>ERROR: The process "2796" not found.
> ```

Comment: Acquaint yourself with  how to ask question. Give sample data input, what you need done and expected output. See this link  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by the security software we are running.

It seems the "real time file scanning" was either blocking some python workers from launching or slowing things down sufficiently that some python workers failed to start within the hard-coded 10 second window within which the worker must connect back to the socket (see [PythonWorkerFactory.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/77339dc6a49d1d9d2a7a3aae966610acbe1a5d6e/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/api/python/PythonWorkerFactory.scala)).